# how to use relational tables in a WPF viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, relational-database, viewmodel

I'm building a N tier WPF app.  I want zero codebehind.

Let's say I have 3 normalized related tables to record sales transactions.

**TRANSACTIONS**:

TransactionId,
ItemId,
SupplierId,
Price

**SUPPLIERS**:

SupplierId,
SupplierName

**ITEMS**:

ItemId,
ItemName.

For each table I have a Base class that reflects the fields.  Then a data layer that populates a collection of base objects as required.

I want to have a Listbox on the page showing a list of all of the transactions, 1 transaction per row, the rows should look something like this...

```
"Trainers  FootLocker   €99"

"Trousers  TopShop      €45"

"Coat      TopShop      €49"
```

If I use the

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Transactions}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTransaction}"
```

then I end up with rows of IDs from the Transactions table and not the Name values from the Items and Suppliers tables.

Given that I have collection of transactions filled with only IDs to the other tables, what is the best approach to populating the listbox?

One thing I'm wondering is, should my Transactions Base object contain Item item populated there instead of int ItemId?

Transaction Base Model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using PFT;
using PFT.Data;

namespace PFT.Base
{



    public class Transaction : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        private int _itemId;
        public int ItemId
        {
            get { return _itemId; }
            set { 
                _itemId = value;

                ItemData id = new ItemData();
                this.Item = id.Select(value);

                NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemId");
            }
        }

        private Item _item;

        public Item Item
        {
            get { return _item; }
            set { _item = value; }
        }


        private float _price;
        public float Price
        {
            get { return _price; }
            set { 
                _price = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Price");
            }
        }

        private DateTime _date;
        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return _date; }
            set { 
                _date = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Date");
            }
        }


        private string _comment;
        public string Comment
        {
            get { return _comment; }
            set
            {
                _comment = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Comment");
            }
        }

        private int _traderId;
        public int TraderId
        {
            get { return _traderId; }
            set
            {
                _traderId = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TraderId");
            }
        }

        private Trader _trader;

        public Trader Trader
        {
            get { return _trader; }
            set { _trader = value;

            TraderData t = new TraderData();
            this.Trader = t.Select(value);
            }
        }


        private string _insertType;
        /// <summary>
        /// A - Auto, M - Manual, V - Verified
        /// </summary>
        public string InsertType
        {
            get { return _insertType; }
            set { _insertType = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("InsertType");
            }
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
        //private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

ITEMS BASE CLASS

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace PFT.Base
{
    public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }



        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }


        private string _description;

        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }


        private float _defaultPrice;

        public float DefaultPrice
        {
            get { return _defaultPrice; }
            set { _defaultPrice = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DefaultPrice");
            }
        }

        private bool _isIncome;

        public bool IsIncome
        {
            get { return _isIncome; }
            set { _isIncome = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsIncome");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you styling your `ListBox`? By default the `ListBox` just calls `ToString` on each of its items and displays the resulting string.

Comment: So basically, you have 3 collections (Suppliers, Transactions, and Items) and you want to join them into a single row to display for each Transaction?

Comment: Could there be more than one Supplier or Item for each Transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you'd do this with viewmodels would be to give `Transaction` a `Supplier` property and an `Item` property. Those properties would be references to the actual `Item` and `Supplier` objects in their own collections. If the relationship is one `ItemID` and one `SupplierID` per transaction, that's the object equivalent. If a transaction can be multiple records with the same transaction ID and different supplier or item IDs, then `Transaction` needs *collections* of `Item` and `Supplier`. We can do that in WPF too, but it'll take a lot more angle brackets than the trivial example below.

You would set that up when you get your items from the database (however you're doing that), or maybe Entity Framework can do that for you.

Real simple listbox displaying item names: Add `DisplayMemberPath`.

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTransaction}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Item.Name"
    />
```

More complicated:

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTransaction}"
    >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Item.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Run Text=" - " />
                <Run Text="{Binding Supplier.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Run Text=" " />
                <Run Text="{Binding Price, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=c}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You could also look into a columned control like a `ListView` or `DataGrid`.

Slightly off topic, zero code-behind is a bit extreme. It's a last resort, not a third rail. Minimal code-behind is a sound general principle. Don't go crazy trying to avoid it; it's there for a reason.

## UPDATE

```
public class Transaction : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //  ... stuff ...

    public Item Item
    {
        get { return _item; }
        set { 
            _item = value; 
            //  If this property is ever set outside the Transaction 
            //  constructor, you ABSOLUTELY MUST raise PropertyChanged here. 
            //  Otherwise, make the setter private. But just raise the event.

            //  This has nothing whatsoever to do with when or whether the Item 
            //  class raises PropertyChanged, because this is not a property of the 
            //  Item class. This is a property of Transaction. 

            NotifyPropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }

    //  ... more stuff ...
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly I am adding the Item item property to my Transaction Base class.  Then this would be Transactions.Item.ItemName in the xaml.  
  That kind of knocks the purity out of the base class.  I'm wondering is this the right approach?  Should I maybe extend the class instead?  decisions decisions!

Comment: I'm building with a view to Xamarin multi platform phone apps so zero code behind is ideal.  I have it reduced to about 1 line per page setting up the datacontext - it's great and well worth the effort.

Comment: *"this would be Transactions.Item.ItemName in the xaml"* -- no, that would not work at all. `Transactions` does not have an `Item` property. `Transactions` is a collection class of some kind, hopefully `ObservableCollection<Transaction>`. The XAML would be what I showed you. I don't see any purity issue. The reason you're writing a Transaction class is to model an association between an Item, a Supplier, and a Price.

Comment: Usually, a view should get its data context from the parent view rather than setting it up in code behind, so you very often don't even have that.

Comment: Sorry Ed. Still not fully understanding.   I should have written Transaction.Item.Name  (No S). 

_"The way you'd do this with viewmodels would be to give Transaction a Supplier property and an Item property"_  Where should this be added in the BASE model?

Comment: I don't know what the BASE model is. Can you add the BASE model source code to your question?

Comment: So originally I only had `int ItemId` to represent the database field but in the code above I've added `Item Item` as I'm trying that out as we _speak_.

Comment: @RayBrennan Looks good. One thing, in the setter for `Item` I would not neglect to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("Item");`, just as you're doing with `Price` and all the others

Comment: _"One thing, in the setter for Item I would not neglect to call NotifyPropertyChanged("Item")"_  
`INotifyPropertyChanged` is in every base class so I shouldn't need to call it again when `Item` base is used.
I'm at work so I can't test it yet to respond to you properly.

Comment: No idea what that means.

Comment: Can you explain what "`Item` base" is and show me where it's defined? If you're talking about the `Item` property that gets set in the setter for the `ItemId` property, believe me, there is no ambiguity here: You just have to raise `PropertyChanged`. You just have to do that. That's how viewmodels work. The base class can't do it for you.

Comment: In the Transactions class we're creating the property `public Item item`.  The Item class has the `INotifyPropertyChanged `. So any change to that Item property will cause the notifications to be handled there.  No need to do it in the Transactions Item setter.
  Getting confusing :)

Comment: I've added the Items Base to the code above.   Notifications for Items are handled in there.

Comment: See update. I think you may be confused, but I assure you I'm not.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I'll have a play with it later when I get a chance.  At least I have that to keep in mind if it's not working :)